# ggplot2 bar plot with column titles as x values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe as below:

```
 A     B     C     D     E     F
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1290. 3916. 4514. 5498. 5028  1987 
2  798. 3777  5598  5428. 6160. 4668.
3 1212. 3594  6315  6740  6560. 6490.
4 1224  5592. 6203  6230  6304.   NA 
5  996  2491  3938. 4972  5062  4308.
6  524  3466. 4658. 5044. 4981  4295
```

I want to make a bar plot with error bars where A, B, C, D, E, F are x values and the corresponding column values are averaged and used as the y values. Also, I have some NA cells in my dataset but I'd like to ignore it when taking average e.g. with na.rm(), instead of removing whole columns or rows. Could you guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would help if you can provide a reprex. If you type `dput(df)` into your console, and paste the output in your post, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reshape your dataframe into a longer format for example using `pivot_longer` function of `tidyr` package and calculate the mean of each group.

For example using `dplyr` and `tidyr` package, you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "X", values_to = "Y") %>%
  group_by(X) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Y, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Mean))+
  geom_col()
```

Here, an application of the code below using the following dummy example mimicking your data:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = sample(1000:9999,6),
                 B = sample(1000:9999,6),
                 C = sample(1000:9999,6),
                 D = sample(1000:9999,6))
df[4,4]<- NA

     A    B    C    D
1 1499 6992 1866 5793
2 5479 2596 4945 2399
3 7193 1043 2623 2007
4 9464 7624 6758   NA
5 6716 2270 4119 1600
6 5563 4771 8427 7973
```

If you apply the code below, you can get:

[image]

Does it answer your question ?